# Flutter WebRTC can't create datachannel

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I'm trying to create WebRTC datachannel with [flutter_webrtc](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc) package but have some Issues.

What I'm doing:

I'm creating `RTCPeerConnection? _peerConnection;`. I have working video and audio stream.
But then I'm trying to add `dataChannels`.

On Offer side I do:

```dart
  _createDataChanel() async {
    final chanInit = RTCDataChannelInit()
      ..negotiated = true
      ..maxRetransmits = 30;

    _dataChannel = await _peerConnection!.createDataChannel('chat', chanInit);
    _dataChannel!.onMessage = (data) {
      print(data);
    };
  }
```

On Answer side I do:

```dart
  _subscribeDataChanel() {
    _peerConnection!.onDataChannel = (channel) {
      _dataChannel = channel;
      _dataChannel!.onMessage = (data) {
        print(data);
      };
    };
  }
```

And nothing happens. It will never send any events to `onDataChannel`. May be I do something wrong?

**UPD:** I made some experiments and figure how to solve.

**Solution:** We should firstly create DataChannel and then create Offer or Answer. So in code it will be something like:

Offer side:

```
createOffer(Connection connection) async {
    await _createDataChanel();

    final offerDesc = await _peerConnection!.createOffer(offerSdpConstraints);
    await _peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    // send to signaling server and so on...
}
```

Answer side:

```
createAnswer(Connection connection) async {
    _subscribeDataChanel();
    // get offer from signaling server and so on ...
}
```

Comment: Try adding `..id = -1`

Comment: @DmytroRostopira tried this kind of magic, not working, but I figure out solution and update post

Comment: I am trying to implement chat feature through flutter_webrtc datachannel, can you please share your code for the chat feature, it will be og great help!